# Pandas styling with Python

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, pandas, styles

I am quite new to the `Pandas styling` and trying to style my `Pandas DataFrame` and `colour` the `headers` `grey colour`, here is my attempt:

```
with open ('test.html','w') as test:
    test, df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'}).set_table_styles([ dict(selector='th', props=[('text-align', 'center')] ) ]).render()
```

There are 2 problems and 1 question:

**Problems**

1 - To colour the `headers grey` like the `excel`

2 - exporting as `HTML`

**Question:**
Is it possible to render the finished styled as an excel file as well?

Comment: Do you want to export as `HTML` or `excel` ?

Comment: HTML first, then if it's possible to export excel as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do:

```
def hover(hover_color="#ffff99"):
    return dict(selector="tr:hover",
                props=[("background-color", "%s" % hover_color)])
styles = [
    hover(),
    dict(selector='thead', props=[('background-color','grey')]),
]

# this forces grey background on header
styler = df.style.set_table_styles(styles)

# HTML string
html = styler.render()

# save html
with open('file.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)

# excel
styler.to_excel('file.xlsx')
```

Comment: thanks, the excel headers is not colored. And I did not see the HTML file generated. I want to have the HTML file?

Comment: @Pythonista you are correct, excel file stills doesn't have gray header. See update for `html` saving.